# Compare Images using a database of images using ImageMagick?

Tags: php, imagemagick

I know I can compare two images (to check whether they are **visually the same**, not to check their file format, EXIF, etc.) using `compareImages( Imagick $compare , int $metric )` function of `ImageMagick` library in PHP (also available in several other programming languages).

Sample codes to compare 2 images in PHP:

```
<?php

$image1 = new imagick("image1.png");
$image2 = new imagick("image2.png");
// TODO: have to resize 2 images to same dimension first
$result = $image1->compareImages($image2, Imagick::METRIC_MEANSQUAREERROR);
$result[0]->setImageFormat("png");

header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $result[0]; // display the result
// TODO: Add exception handling
?>
```

But with thousands of images to compare against, this function seems to be inefficient, as it can only compare one by one. Is there any function that I can use to make a fingerprint (something like that) of an image, so that I can easily search in the database?

Methods I can think of:

1. Convert the image to Base64 string
2. Fetch few sample pixels from each image, store the colors in the database (but this method is not accurate)
3. Use Image recognition library (something like Machine Learning) to add some tags for each image, then search by tag (this method is not accurate as well)
4. (anything else?)

All suggestions are welcomed.

p.s. programming language does not necessary to be in PHP.

Comment: You can use perceptual hashes. There are a number of sources for those. I have some variations in my bash unix Imagemagick shell scripts in the module called phashes. See my scripts web site at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php

Comment: That's amazing! I will try out your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`getImageSignature`](http://php.net/manual/de/imagick.getimagesignature.php) function, which will return a string containing the SHA-256 hash of the file.

So either loop over all images and add the image signature to your database of images, or just add the signature on every comparisson you perform.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but from the comments of `getImageSignature` in the link, it seems that the function is not reliable; each version of ImageMagick generates different hash values. I found a similar way to do so: https://realpython.com/fingerprinting-images-for-near-duplicate-detection/